# Add secondary x axis based on pd.Series of strings

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas df that looks like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|      timestamp      |     clocktime    |   value   |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|          1          |       8:30       |    10     |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|          2          |       8:31       |    20     |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
|          3          |       8:33       |    15     |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------|
```

and I've managed to plot it with `timestamp` on the x-axis and `value` on the y-axis. Is there a way to create a secondary x-axis with `clocktime` as it's values? The issue is that i have over 100k rows, so i can't print every `clocktime` entry (each `clocktime` entry is a string). Is there a way to display both `timestamp` and `clocktime` as two separate x-axes on the same plot with some intelligent tick spacing for both? I'm using matplotlib, and plotting it using the `Axes.axes` object.

Comment: Could you edit your post with some code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what "intelligent tick spacing"  mean , but you can do the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
b=pd.DataFrame({"timestamp":[1,2,3],"clocktime": ["8:30","8:31","8:33"],"value":[10,20,15]})
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax1.plot(b["clocktime"], b["value"])
ax2.plot(b["timestamp"], b["value"]) 
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(b["timestamp"]),max(b["timestamp"])+1, 1.0))
plt.show()
```

Comment: What I meant was that I have 100k `clocktime` values, so I can't print all of them, which is precisely why this solution doesn't work for me. What I ended up doing was picking n equally spaced entries from the Series and matching those to my `timestamp` values and only plotting those. Works fine for now